# Page Navigation from a cocos2d scene to Uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

my project is a cocos2d game project, but i added a uiviewcontroller as loginview for the user. first scene in my project is logo showing scene,after that it will goes to the menu screen, but i need to pass to my uiviewcontroller(login)  instead of menu screen,i tried lot of method but crashing.

```
-(id) init
```

{

```
if( (self=[super init] )) {
    CCSprite *sprBack = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"logo.png"];
    [sprBack setPosition:ccp(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2)];
    [self addChild:sprBack];

    [self schedule:@selector(logoTimer:) interval:3];
}

return self;
```

}

```
-(void) logoTimer: (ccTime) dt
```

{

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[TitleLayer node ]  ]];
```

}

my uiviewcontroller name is loginviewcontroller.

i need to pass scene like this

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[loginviewcontroller node ]  ]];
```

but showing error , i tired lot of method but unfortunalty nothing will gives me the  correct solution .

one more thing loginviewcontroller is not node, its uiviewcontroller.
 i have tried this method also but it struck in the logo scene,no page transition taking place.

```
    -(void) logoTimer: (ccTime) dt{

    UIViewController *cocos = [[LogoViewController alloc] init];
    [cocos.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 [cocos.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change and set the initial view controller to Login View Controller in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and move setup of game engine in a `newMethod` in `LoginViewController`. The setup of game creates a new view controller which will open current Menu screen. On the event of successful credentials, call that `newMethod` and then push the view controller that is instantiated in game setup, and pop to go back to login.

Comment: @ICoder, Please let me know if this approach is helpful to you.

Comment: @ bunty my problem is ,first view is logo view which shows splash screen of the screen, then it must go to login view which is a view controller .